# How to reload form in Angular component

Tags: angular

I have a component which is used for route navigation without component reload:

```
export class TableComponent extends SafeComponent implements OnInit {
  customersMe$: Observable<ICompanyCustomer>;
  customersMe: ICompanyCustomer;
  tables$: Observable<ITable[]>;
  headersLoaded$: Observable<boolean>;
  headerLoading = true;

  table: ITable;
  TableForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private store: Store<State>,
    private router: Router,
    private route:ActivatedRoute,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tables$ = this.store.pipe(select(getTables));
    this.headersLoaded$ = this.store.pipe(select(getLoaded));

    combineLatest([this.tables$, this.headersLoaded$, this.route.params])
      .subscribe(([tables, loaded, params]) => {
        if (loaded) {
          this.headerLoading = false;
          const table = tables.find(x => x.id === Number(params['id']));
          if (table) {
            this.table = table;
          } else {
            // navigate 404
          }
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        }
      })


  /*  this.tableForm = new FormGroup({
   *    start: new FormControl(this.table.time_start),
   *    end: new FormControl(this.table.time_finish)
   *});*/

  }
}
```

As you notice here I subscribe to route and update data on new id in route path.
How can I update data in Form Group? Thank you!

Comment: hi if you just wanna know how to update a form take a look about patchValue ? exemple : ```this.form.patchValue({
  name: 'Todd Motto',
  event: {
    title: 'AngularCamp 2016',
    location: 'Barcelona, Spain'
  }
});```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to populate the form fields with values, you could try:
For populating all fields:

```
this.form.setValue({name: 'Kakashi', address: { village: 'Konoha', country: 'Fire'}});
```

For populating some fields:

```
this.form.patchValue({name: 'Kakashi', address: { village: 'Konoha', country: 'Fire'}});
```

Answer (score 2):

In Angular If you want to reload the form. then you need to do like this,

```
this.form.reset();
```

& when you are on a new route then you can do this.

```
this.form.patchValue({name: '---', age:'---'});
```